# How to send a database to another Activity in android studio

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I build a database in Activity A, and when adding the data, I want the App go to the Activity B so that user can enter their information. I am trying to use `intent.putExtra()` in Activity A and `get.Intent()` function in Activity B, but this doesn't work for the class, database, I create.  What should I do? 
I also try create a new database in Activity B with same parameter, but first there is also a error, and second I don't think it would be the same database.
I believe there are better method to implement this function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code??

Answer (score 0):

There are some option available

1. in your Activity A
   put your database variable in public static

   ```
   public class AActivity extends Activity {
           //this is your database, ready to share it in another activity
           public static SQLiteDatabase db;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ......................
   ```
2. in your Activity B
   instantiate your variable with same db, you can use it in another activity too

   ```
   public class BActivity extends Activity {
           //use database from AActivity
           SQLiteDatabase db = AActivity.db;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // you can do everything for database, use db here

           ......................
   ```
3. user enter the info in BActivity, and submit it.

if AActivity show some data info, don't forget to reload it, after submit data in BActivity.